# Setting wbkDest.worksheets("xxxxxxx") to Reflect a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that generates pages/page names. The worksheet name always reflects a job number. The job number is also always displayed in cell A1.

I want to copy data from another book, and paste it back into this worksheet, but I need to target the page I want to paste the data.

My issue is that I can't say `wbkDest.Worksheets("sheet1")`.
I need to say something like `wbk.Dest.Worksheets(Range("a1").value)`.

So again: Paste in the sheet with the same name as cell A1 in the workbook the macro is triggered from.

```
sub import()
    Dim wbkSrc As Workbook, wbkDest As Workbook
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim wsOrig As Worksheet
    Set wsOrig = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 

    emptyRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wbkDest = Workbooks("lathe_project6-1-2017.xlsm")
    Path = "G:\FIXTURES\" & Range("A1").Value & "\lists\new folder\"
    myFile = Dir(Path & "*.xls??")
    Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & myFile)
    wbkSrc.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:I100").Copy

    wbkDest.Worksheets(wsOrig.Range("A1").Value).Cells(emptyRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wbkSrc.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: So cell **A1** in the newly created worksheet matches the name of that worksheet ??

Comment: Yes. At project kick off the manager enters the job number into the first splash page. once entered, it generates a page off a template the has the job number as the sheet title. The job number is also put in A1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:?

```
Dim wskVariableSheet as worksheet
Set wskVariableSheet = wbkDest.Sheets(Range("a1").Value)
```

And then just reference to `wskVariableSheet.range` where you want to paste.

Comment: When I try I get a compilation error right at the beginning.

Comment: @mystic_muffin It may be useful if you paste more of your code into the question.  Maaajo's code should have worked without any issues, so maybe you placed it into the wrong spot - with more of your code included in the question it will be easier to explain exactly what you need to change.

Comment: added it into my original post.